# How to Record Screen + Web Cam on Mac

Tags: mac, video, recording

I want to make a recording of a presentation where I want to keep slides on screen and have a box inside that screen's view, capturing through webcam as well.

I've done a basic search but can't figure it out. How can do this?

Comment: I'm afraid that asking for product recommendations is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free program called OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) that will allow you to record the screen as well as have a webcam in the corner with minimal configuration.

Guide: https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-record-with-obs-add-a-webcam-text-settings-explained-video.80/

Mac Download: https://obsproject.com/download